# pinping in unix.. I faced a proplem in the result of more than one piping

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I try to read and print the data from a c file that sorted 4 lines of student name , major,level,credet hou and GPA and I want to do that ""Display highest & lowest level and the
corresponding student name" with writing these command

```
echo | sort -n -k 3 | cut -f 1,3 | head -n 1 /home/areej7/file.c
echo | sort -n -k 3 | cut -f 1,3 | tail -n 1 /home/areej7/file.c
```

the result not mathch what we want

where's the wrong?is it in the order of the commands in piping ?

Comment: `echo` by itself just outputs one empty line. What do you expect from sorting an empty line?

Answer (score 1):

You need to feed the file into the start of the pipeline.

```
cat /home/areej7/file.c | sort -n -k 3 | cut -f 1,3 | head -n 1  
cat /home/areej7/file.c | sort -n -k 3 | cut -f 1,3 | tail -n 1
```

Comment: I write these line in a spearet file and I want to see the result in the terminal when I execute the file ....... so how can i print the result in the terminal

Comment: @Areej If you run these commands in a shell script from the command line and you don't redirect the output, the output should appear in the terminal.  If you don't see anything, debug by removing commands from the end of the pipe until you do.

Comment: whene I writ this on terminal "echo | cat /home/areej7/file.c | sort -n -k 3 | cut -f 1,3 | head -n 1 " there is no output appear ,why?

Comment: @Areej First, git rid of the `echo` at the start.  Then start removing commands from the end.

Comment: but I want the result in the same time

Comment: @Areej The "echo" is causing empty text to be pushed into the pipeline.  Leave it out.

Comment: I write this command "sort -n -k 3 | cut -f 1,3 | head -n 1 /home/areej7/file.c | echo" in the  shell file , Plz just tell me how can I sorted the command to get the rigth result

Comment: @Areej You keep changing the command.  Use **exactly** what's in the answer.

Comment: @Areej Type this **exact** command:  `cat /home/areej7/file.c | sort -n -k 3 | cut -f 1,3 | head -n 1`

Comment: @Areej If you don't see any output, take commands off the end of the pipe until you do, i.e. `cat /home/areej7/file.c | sort -n -k 3 | cut -f 1,3`, then `cat /home/areej7/file.c | sort -n -k 3`, etc.

Comment: cat /home/areej7/file.c | sort -n -k 3 | cut -f 1,3 | head -n 1 this work coorectly ,but command cut isn't execute !

Comment: @dbush: Maybe you could [get rid of the `cat`](https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html)?

Comment: @Arrej : All commands in the pipe get executed, unless you aborts - but then you get a broken pipe error. Perhaps some of the commands don't return what you expect them to return? For debugging, you can place `tee` commands into the pipe and check the result, for instance `sort -n -k 3 ~areej7/file.c  | tee f1 | cut -f 1,3 | tee f2 | head -n 1`. After this, `f1` and `f2` contain the interim results of the pipe.

Comment: @Areej : Having said this: If file.c really contains the source code of a C-program, as its name suggests, why on earth would anybody want to sort the source code of a program???